# How to deserialize a ClientResponse body in Spring test environment?

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-webflux

I'm trying to create a `ClientResponse` in test and use it for testing a service, which also does deserialization with standard  way `response.bodyToMono(..class..)`. But it appears that there is something wrong in the way I build a fake client response. Because I receive `UnsupportedMediaTypeException` in tests.

Nevertheless the same code work fine in runtime SpringBoot app, when WebClient returns `ClientResponse` (which is built internally).

Let's see at the simplest case hich fails with

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException:
             Content type 'application/json' not supported for bodyType=java.lang.String[]
```

---

```
 void test()
 {
   String body = "[\"a\", \"b\"]";
   ClientResponse response = ClientResponse.create(HttpStatus.OK)
                                           .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, 
                                                   MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                                           .body(body)
                                           .build();

   String[] array = response.bodyToMono(String[].class).block();

   assertEquals(2, array.length);
}
```

Please, help me to undeerstand, how the client response should be build to allow a standard (json -> object) deserialization in test environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `ClientResponse` created manually does not have access to `Jackson2Json` exchange strategies in default list. Probably it could be configured with Spring auto-configuration, which is turned off in tests without Spring context.

Here is the straightforward way to force (de)serialization String <-> json:

```
static ExchangeStrategies jacksonStrategies()
{
    return ExchangeStrategies
            .builder()
            .codecs(clientDefaultCodecsConfigurer ->
            {
                clientDefaultCodecsConfigurer.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonEncoder(new Jackson2JsonEncoder(new ObjectMapper(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
                clientDefaultCodecsConfigurer.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonDecoder(new Jackson2JsonDecoder(new ObjectMapper(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

            }).build();
}
```

Then use it in the `create` function

```
ClientResponse.create(HttpStatus.OK, jacksonStrategies())...
```